# C++ 'Hello World' with Codelite-iostream not found

Tags: gcc, c++, debugging

I appreciate any help with this, as I am relatively new to both Linux and coding in general.  I am comfortable using bash commands and have been playing with Linux for a little over a year, but please be patient as I may not know all terminology or methods.

- My objective is to learn c++.
- I am using the Codelite IDE,version 9.0.0 and Ubuntu 14.04.
- After attempting to run a basic 'Hello World' program, I ran into a problem that I haven't been able to resolve after lots of google/searching posts here. 'iostream' does not seem to be identified when I try to build.
- I have installed development libraries, and have even located 'iostream' manually in 
  `/usr/include/c++/4.8.4`.
- When setting up the project, I selected the g++ compiler.

What could be the cause of this not building correctly?(edit)

This is the source and resulting error message(s):

---

```
    # include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
            std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
            return 0;

    }
```

---

```
    /bin/sh -c 'usr/bin/make -j2 -e -f Makefile'
    --------Building project:[ HelloWorld - Release ]-------
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/someuser/Codelite/HelloWorld'
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/someuser/Codelite/HelloWorld'
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/someuser/Codelite/HelloWorld'
    /usr/bin/gcc -c "/home/someuser/Codelite/HelloWorld/main.c" -02 -Wall -DNDEBUG -o ./Release/main.c.o -I. -I.
    /home/someuser/Codelite/HelloWorld/main.c:1:20 fatal error: iostream:No such file or directory
    #include <iostream>
                    ^
    compilation terminated.
    make[1]: *** [Release/main.c.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/someuser/Codelite/Helloworld'
    make: *** [All] Error 2
    ====2 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Comment: This compiled fine for me in a terminal, can you try that to see it is a  IDE problem. Save the code as hi.cpp (or whatever, but use .cpp) open a terminal and run `g++ path/to/your/.cpp` and press enter, this will give you an file called a.out in your /home, run it in a terminal and it will say `hello world`, it worked for me, there is nothing wrong with the code, exept because you are `using namespace std;` you don't need `std::cout` just `cout` as you already included `std`.

Comment: That sure works!  I guess it is an IDE problem.  Thank you for the concise answer, I appreciate it.  Using the terminal seems much more straightforward.

Comment: I use a text editor (gedit, preinstalled) and it can do syntax highlighting when you save your file with an extension (Ie .ccp) and just a terminal, when you compile terminal will debug too, in my opinion an IDE is a waste, you don't need it on Ubuntu, it is made for development, just use a text editor and a terminal, I promise it works great on Ubuntu, you won't go back to a bulky IDE, I never did :)

Comment: Yes, I used gedit.  I'll probably continue with this method.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is because your selected a `gcc` template and not `g++`.
CodeLite will execute `gcc` for files with the `.c` extension.

1. Right click on `main.c` in the project view and select <kbd>Rename</kbd>
2. Change it to `main.cpp`
3. Compile your code and it should work

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Your answer works.

Comment: You're a legend. Created an account just to say this.